# Can't extract data with regexp

Tags: python, python-re

I have strings like this  `dict({'{"Key": "Val", "Key2": "AZZ2"}':`

I want to extract `{"Key": "Val", "Key2": "AZZ2"}` with help of `re` library

I was trying

```
import re

PATTERN=re.compile(r'dict\({(\w+)')
s = """dict({'{"Key": "Val", "Key2": "AZZ2"}"""
res = PATTERN.findall(s)
```

What pattern should i use?

Comment: Are you trying to extract dictionary representation?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pattern:

```py
PATTERN = re.compile(r"(?<=dict\({').*[^\)]")
s = """dict({'{"Key": "Val", "Key2": "AZZ2"}"""
res = PATTERN.findall(s)
print(res)
>>> ['{"Key": "Val", "Key2": "AZZ2"}']
```

It create a positive look behind for `dict({'`, then add all other characters until it finds a `)`.

The result is a list because you used the `findall` function from the re library.

EDIT:
If you want to use the string as a python dictionary you can use `eval`:

```
d = eval(res[0])
type(d)  #dict
d.keys() # dict_keys(['Key', 'Key2'])
```